# Postgres backup endlessly

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Hi guys I need of your help.

Yesterday, at 3 pm, I started a backup process of my db, I'm working with postgresql, and now the process is running.

This is a test db so its size is about 200 mb, so I think something doesn't work.

I'm using PgAdmin 4, and I didn't find a way to stop the process, so I restar the pc, but when I opened PgAdmin, the process restarted.

How can I stop the process?

Comment: Use [command-line tools](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup.html) directly instead of PgAdmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I found the solution the problem is related to the pgadmin.db, and I removed. It can be found in C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin